# Three.js restoring webglcontext

Tags: three.js

What components of a three.js scene need to be recreated when restoring the webglcontext? 
For example, can I;`scene.add( myoldcamera );`
Or do I need to do;`scene.add( new Camera() );`
And is it different depending on the object type? e.g. Materials, Lights, Meshes etc.

Answer (score 0):

When a context is lost in a webGL program, it never gets back automatically , we need  to re-create textures, buffers, framebuffers, renderbuffers, shaders, programs, and setup  state (clearColor, blendFunc, depthFunc, etc...) on  **webglcontextrestored** event.

[Here](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/HandlingContextLost) you can get more info .

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm asking about three.js objects. I'm not manipulating webGL directly. Do any three.js objects get broken by a loss of graphics context, or can I simple just re-add them again to a scene?

Comment: ya you can add/remove objects from scene , no need to define camera and scene again

Comment: So are you saying my three.js app will survive the reinitialization of the graphics context without any action having to be taken by me?